# bcp Load data from CSV into Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, import, bcp

Attempting to upload a CSV file to Azure via bcp. Command will run and returns 0 rows copied.

I suspect it is a formatting issue but I cannot figure out where. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

file format:

> field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12,field13,field14

Format file:

> 12.0 14 1       SQLCHAR             2       100     ""   1     field1                                                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 2       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   2     field2
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 3       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   3     field3
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 4       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   4     field4
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 5       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   5     field5
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 6       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   6     field6
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 7       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   7     field7
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 8       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   8     field8
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 9       SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   9     field9
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 10      SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   10    field10
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 11      SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   11    field11
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 12      SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   12    field12
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 13      SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   13    field13
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 14      SQLCHAR             2       100
>   ""   14    field14
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Powershell command:

```
bcp tableName in C:\FileToLoad.csv -c -f fileFormat-c.fmt -S serverName -d databaseName -U user -P password
```