# Is there a UI based way to load csv data to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, etl

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to load data into an Azure SQL Database. I'm aware of all the methods referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622814/push-data-to-azure-sql-database) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098618/bcp-load-data-from-csv-into-azure-sql-database) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785932/loading-csv-from-azure-data-lake-gen-2-to-azure-sql-database) as well as various ETL tools. By far, it looks like bcp using SSMS is the easiest way. 
My question is, is there an easier UI based way to load data from a file into a table, either via a bucket(blob storage) or directly uploaded like we can in Google BigQuery or AWS RedShift or Athena or Glue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the Azure Data Factory Copy Data tool as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool).

1.On the Let's get started page, select the Copy Data tile to launch the Copy Data tool.

[image]

2.On the Properties page, under Task name, enter CopyFromBlobToSqlPipeline. Then select Next. The Data Factory UI creates a pipeline with the specified task name.

[image]

3.On the Source data store page, complete the following steps:

3a. Click + Create new connection to add a connection

[image]

3b. Select Azure Blob Storage from the gallery, and then select Next.

[image]

3c. On the New Linked Service page, select your storage account from the Storage account name list, and then select Finish.

[image]

3d. Select the newly created linked service as source, then click Next.

[image]

4.On the Choose the input file or folder page, complete the following steps:

4a. Click Browse to navigate file, then click Choose.

[image]

4b. Click Next to move to next step.

5.On the File format settings page, notice that the tool automatically detects the column and row delimiters. Select Next. You also can preview data and view the schema of the input data on this page.

[image]

6.On the Destination data store page, completes the following steps:

6a. Click + Create new connection to add a connection

[image]

6b. Select Azure SQL Database from the gallery, and then select Next.

[image]

6c. On the New Linked Service page, select your server name and DB name from the dropdown list, and specify the username and password, then select Finish.

[image]

6d. Select the newly created linked service as sink, then click Next.

[image]

7.On the Table mapping page, select the table, and then select Next.

9.On the Settings page, select Next.

10.On the Summary page, review the settings, and then select Next.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all the methods you sited are the only ones currently supported, Data Factory is not a UI based solution but could possibly be easy, more information about it can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953637/is-there-a-ui-based-way-to-load-csv-data-to-azure-sql-database)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the Import Wizard with SSMS. It can help you import the csv file into the table most directly.

Here's the [Exporting Data from SQL Azure: Import/Export Wizard](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/exporting-data-from-sql-azure-importexport-wizard/)

Here is how to import from SQL Azure:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, connect to your Azure SQL database.
2. Right click on that database and choose from the drop down context menu `Tasks` | `Import Data`.
   [image]
3. Choose a data Source: Azure Blob Source.
   [image]
4. Choose a Destination: SQL Server Native Client 11.0.
   [image]

5.Select Source Tables and Views: select the csv files.
[image]

6. Preview Data Type Mapping.
   [image]
7. Save and Run Package: run immediately and complete the Wizard.
   [image]
8. Finsh.

[image]

You will load data from the csv file in Azure Blob into a table in Azure SQL database.

Hope this helps.